# Canonical Redirect with classic ASP shows site folder

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, canonicalization

If pointed to http://domain.com it redirects to http://www.domain.com/thesite/index.asp which is the actual location. No matter the page, it always appends the actual folder path.

ive been using this script for canonical redirection, included in every page.

```
 If InStr(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"),"www") = 0 Then
   Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
   Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www." &_ 
   Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")&_ 
   Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
 End if
```

I have several sites in a shared hosting, each in its own folder.

How can i prevent this?

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after further diggin' i finally bumped into a solution. Turns out IIS7 had url redirection rules enabled, so this can be accomplished through web.config, like this

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I overlooked it before cause it was listed as ASP.NET solution, not classic ASP.
But there it is, solved.